# Root window auto fills screen

Tags: tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Show Please")
root.geometry("800x800")

root.mainloop()
```

This code should work to create a small root window, however it just auto fills my screen, no title bar or anything.
I'm not sure about windows or Linux or Mac or any of those.  But, I am using pydroid3. Please only provide pydroid3 answers because I'm sure on windows there is no problem.

I have tried adding root.resizable(True, True)
And if I create a button that opens a second root window or even a Toplevel, the second one works just fine

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Show Please")
root.geometry("800x800")

def Openroot2()
    root.destroy()
    root2 = Tk()
    root2.title("works fine")
    root2.geometry("500x500")
    root2.mainloop()

but1 = Button(root, text = 'Click me', command = Openroot2)
but1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The first root window is just the size of the screen and nothing I can do about it, the second one works fine.  Do I really need to create a second root window every time if I want it resizable and then just treat root2 as if I'm on the top layer and create my Toplevels and widgets and code for root2. Or is there a way to completely remove the need for a second root window?

```
Again please only provide pydroid3
Answers because I don't think
Windows or Mac has this problem
```

Answer (score 1):

OK so I found the answer. If anyone else encounters this. Go to settings, click system, scroll all the way until you find Tkinter:maximize first window. Disable it. If it's on, it will generate the first window in full screen whether you want UT to or not.

```
wish I didn't wait an hour for no
reply and figured it out solo.
```

Comment: *"wish I didn't wait an hour for no
reply"* - StackOverflow is a free website so people answering questions can't be available 24/7. Also there aren't a lot of people that have experience with `pydroid3` and `tkinter` that can answer any question you have.